# Index error when trying to write to text file

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a program to list the Fibonacci numbers up to `n=21` and to write them to  a txt file in the format:

```
n  Fn  
0  0  
1  1  
2  1  etc
```

I have managed to print out all the numbers but i am having trouble writing them to the file.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
       return n
    else:                      
       return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

n = 22

for i in range(n):   
    print(i, fib(i))

np.savetxt('fibonacci.txt',fib(i), header =" n Fn")
```

I am also aware that this code would only write the values of Fn but i dont know how to write to the file in the format i'm looking for

At the moment this code gives me the error:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: You cannot use `np.savetxt` to save numbers to a file.

Comment: I do not get your error running this code, instead I get `ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead`, which makes sense given the fact that `np.savetxt` takes a `1D` or `2D` array as input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to pretend like this isn't a homework assignment.

In python, the more [typical way to write text to a file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) would be something along the lines of:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as F:
    F.write('n\tFn\n')
    for i in range(n):
        F.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(i, fib(i)))
```

Also, your `fib` function should use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), or if you want to totally side-step the assignment and learn nothing, use the [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).

Answer (score 0):

You need to save array data to file, while using np.savetext function.
Try this one:

```
import numpy as np

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
       return n
    else:                      
       return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

n = 22

data = []
for i in range(n):
    row = []
    row.append(i)
    row.append(fib(i))
    data.append(row)

print(data)

np.savetxt('fibonacci.txt',data, header =" n Fn")
```